# Delete records in Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm trying to delete a record in Doctrine, but I don't know why it's not deleting.

**Here is my Code:**

```
function del_user($id)
{
    $single_user = $entityManager->find('Users', $id);

    $entityManager->remove($single_user);

    $entityManager->flush();
}
```

**Plus: How can I echo query to see what going on here?**

Comment: it should be like this `$entity = $em->getRepository('ProjectYourBundle:User')->find($id);` ?

Comment: you are missing `getRepository`

Answer (score 45):

This is an old question and doesn't seem to have an answer yet. For reference I am leaving that here for more reference. Also you can check the [doctrine documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#removing-entities)

To delete a record, you need to ( assuming you are in your controller ):

```
// get EntityManager
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

// Get a reference to the entity ( will not generate a query )
$user = $em->getReference('ProjectBundle:User', $id);

// OR you can get the entity itself ( will generate a query )
// $user = $em->getRepository('ProjectBundle:User')->find($id);

// Remove it and flush
$em->remove($user);
$em->flush();
```

Using the first method of getting a [reference](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/advanced-configuration.html#reference-proxies) is usually better if you just want to delete the entity without checking first whether it exists or not, because it will not query the DB and will only create a proxy object that you can use to delete your entity.

If you want to make sure that this ID corresponds to a valid entity first, then the second method is better because it will query the DB for your entity before trying to delete it.

Comment: Question .. this issues 2 SQL commands one to find, one to delete.  Is that a good thing?

Comment: @Dennis It depends on your needs. I updated my answer to cover your question. Thanks.

Comment: Can I ask whether this is a the same as `$em->remove()` and it's just an old question where this hadn't been implemented yet?

Answer (score 4):

For my understanding if you need to delete a record in doctrine that have a doctrine relationship eg. OneToMany, ManyToMany and association cannot be easy deleted until you set the field that reference to another relation equal to null.

......

you can use this for non relation doctrine

```
  $entityManager=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
 $single_user=$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['id'=>$id]);

    $entityManager->remove($single_user);

    $entityManager->flush();
```

but for relation doctrine set the field that reference to another relation to null

```
$entityManager=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
     $single_user=$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['id'=>$id]);
     {# assume you have field that reference #}
       
       $single_user->setFieldData(null);
        $entityManager->remove($single_user);

    $entityManager->flush();
```

Answer (score 2):

do you check your entity as the good comment annotation ?

```
cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true
```

Answer (score 1):

In a Silex route I do like this, in case it helps someone:

```
$app->get('/db/order/delete', function (Request $request) use ($app) {
...

  $id = $request->query->get('id');

  $em = $app['orm.em']; //or wherever your EntityManager is
  $order = $em->find("\App\Entity\Orders",$id); //your Entity

  if($order){
    try{
      $em->remove($order);
      $em->flush();
    }
    catch( Exception $e )
    {
      return new Response( $e->getMessage(), 500 );
    }
    return new Response( "Success deleting order " . $order->getId(), 200 );
  }else{
    return new Response("Order Not Found", 500);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need repository.

```php
$entityManager->getRepository('Users')->find($id);
```

instead of

```
$single_user = $entityManager->find('Users', $id);
```

'Users' String is the name of the Users repository in doctrine ( depends if you are using Symfony , Zend . . etc ).

Comment: This question has the *symfony2* tag, why did you mentioned Zend?

Comment: because is wrong to state this as a symfony2 question, it's a doctrine question

Comment: This isn't that relevant and should be a comment, not an answer, since it doesn't even provide a solution.

Answer (score 0):

First, You may need to check if 'Users' is your fully qualified class name. If not check, and update it to your class name with the namespace info.

Make sure the object returned by find() is not null or not false and is an instance of your entity class before calling EM's remove().

Regarding your other question, instead of making doctrine return SQL's I just use my database (MySQL) to log all queries (since its just development environment).

Answer (score -2):

try a `var_dump()` of your `$single_user`. If it is "`null`", it doens't exist ?

Also check if "Users" is a valid Entity name (no namespace?), and does the $id reference the PK of the user?

If you want to see the queries that are executed check your mysql/sql/... log or look into Doctrine`\DBAL\Logging\EchoSQLLogger`